# Passing JSON in variable to HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

```
  function b(data){
           document.write(data);
          $('#graphContainer').highcharts(data);
      }
```

I need to pass JSON to .highcharts() API.

Using document.write() i have printed that the value of data is:

```
{"chart" : { "type" : "line"} , "title" : { "text" : "First Time Fix Rate"} , "xAxis" : { "title" : { "text" : "Time"} , "categories" : [ 2009.0 , 2010.0 , 2011.0 , 2012.0 , 2013.0]} , "yAxis" : { "title" : { "text" : "FTFR"}} , "plotOptions" : { "series" : { "cursor" : "pointer" , "point" : { "events" : { "click" :function () {alert (this.category+':' + this.y);}}}}} , "tooltip" : { "pointFormat" : "{series.name} produced {point.y:,.0f}
warheads in {point.x}"} , "series" : [ { "data" : [ 100.0 , 222.0 , 555.0 , 367.0 , 100.0]}]}
```

If I manually place this in

> $('#graphContainer').highcharts(data);

removing the white spaces, graph is getting generated. but if want chart to be generated dynamically, its failing without any javascript error.

I tried json2.js, JSON.parse and Stringify, but that didn't solve the issue. Am i missing something?

If i set the data in session from my client code and access it using scriplet ie `$('#graphContainer').highcharts(<%=session1.getAttribute("data")%>);` it works fine. I wonder whats wrong with variables?

I cant use session here.

Comment: And if you just do `data = data.replace(/ /g, '');` before the document.write?

Comment: you want dynamic chart with json data?

Answer (score 1):

Generally in json you cannot use functions, so it can cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a chart from the json data from another source. But what I have done is, I have created the series array programmatically and then asigned the array in the Highchart chart' series value. Not sure though if this helps you.

Comment: cant have template here in jsp bro

Comment: i did not know it also works like what you are showing. new learning for me. thanks. +1